# How do I configure log4j.xml for a web app?

Tags: java, xml, web-applications, log4j, weblogic

I am trying to run a java application on webLogic and I use log4j.
I put the log4j.xml in WebContent/WEB-INF both eclipse and webLogic server(when i try to run the application on the server and eclipse in problems) say that A DOCTYPE is not allowed in content.
I understand the problem comes from the log4j.xml containing the first line below:

```
<element><!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd"></element>
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
...
</log4j:configuration>
```

. Is the log4j.xml not supposed to be placed in WebContent folder? is there another way to configure log4j not using !DOCTYPE?

Comment: Can you post the XML file for more detail?

Comment: Have you tried putting your log4j.xml in the WEB-INF/classes folder?

Comment: [Log4j XML Configuration Primer](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XML is not really XML (so you don't even need to look at the log4j stuff).

Doctypes must be declared before the body of the XML document.  You have it in the middle of the "element" tag.  By placing the doctype in the middle of a tag, the document "becomes" not XML.

Comment: Thanks. I got rid of it and it works. I tried also changing the first line to:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
but got an error that the pattern [x][X][m][M][l][L] is not allowed

Comment: That's funny, the first line of an xml document should permit the xml declaration tag (what you typed), but it has to be the absolute first thing encountered, even a leading space / tab / whatever will be invalid.  Either way, what you have works, and good for you!